# How to get json data to RecyclerView from web api using OkHttp in android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, okhttp, webapi

I am new in android also JSON.I am trying to displaying JSON format data from web server using recyclerviw.I have some customer details.I want to display those details in a recyclerview.I know how to get data's from service.But when its come to web api i got confused with json input and json data. I didn't understand how to pull data, when we using web api. Please help me to solve this problem.

my Json input look like this:
url : http://10.40.0.100:3009/api/GACompany/CompanyData

```
{
  "authKey": "CD123",
  "action": "1",
  "idstatus": "",
  "noOfRows": "0",
  "id": "",
  "idApplicationLogin": "",
  "idGACompany": "0",
  "remarks": "",
  "status": "",
  "noOfPointsVerified": "0"
  "fileName": "",
  
}
```

my JSON :

```
{
    "data": {
        "comData": [
            {
                "applicationDate": "08-01-2019 ",
                "idApplicationLogin": "AV32",
                "customerName": "Anu A",
                "stateName": "Kerala",
                "DeadLine": "10-02-2020",
                "readStatus": "Un Read"
            },
            
        ]
        
}
```

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

       
    }

    public void listeners(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

           
            case R.id.inbox_button: {

             //   startActivity(new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class));


                try {

                   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("authKey",Const.Auth_Key_Value);


                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObjectKeyValue);

                     JSONObject inboxDetailObj = new JSONObject();
                     inboxDetailObj.put("authKey", jsonArray);
                     //inboxDetailObj.put("action",4);
                     inboxDetailObj.put("idApplicationLogin",2012);

                    new PullInboxDetails(this, inboxDetailObj).execute();
                 
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            break;

        }

    }

    private static class PullInboxDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        ProgressDialog pd;
        WeakReference<MenuActivity> context;
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
        String url;
        Request request;
        MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset = utf-8");

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        JSONObject resultJson;
        String resultString;
        SharedPreferences shp;


        public PullInboxDetails(MenuActivity contextObj, JSONObject jsonObject) {
            this.context = new WeakReference<>(contextObj);
            this.jsonObject = jsonObject;

            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();
        }

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {

                url = "http://10.10.0.100:3009/api/GACompany/CompanyData";

                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonObject.toString(), JSON);
                request = new Request.Builder()
                        //.header("X-Client-Type", "Android")
                        .header("authKey","")
                        .url(url)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();

            

                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {

                    return "failure";

                }

                resultString = response.body().string();
                Log.e("Log", resultString);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Log", "Exception", e);
                return "failure";
            }

            return "success";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

           // pd.dismiss(); // Error
            if (s.equals("success")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context.get(), FrontActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("value", resultString);
                context.get().startActivity(intent);

            } else if (s.equals("failure")) {

                Toast.makeText(context.get(), "Pull Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                

            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: what's the problem you are having

Comment: @ruben It shows 'PullInboxDetailsFailed'.

Comment: can you try using `postman` that the request is even returning some response, i found it is returning nothing

Comment: @ruben sorry its official data so i just given a sample url. If we give url and input the postman returns Output. My Json output  ``` {
    "data": {
        "comData": [
            {
                "applicationDate": "08-01-2019 ",
                "idApplicationLogin": "AV32",
                "customerName": "Anu A",
                "stateName": "Kerala",
                "DeadLine": "10-02-2020",
                "readStatus": "Un Read"
            },
            
        ]
        
}```

Comment: what you get in logcat? without access i can't check though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating request `JSON object` like this, all `key` in one `jsonObject`:

```
JSONObject inboxDetailObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    inboxDetailObj.put("authKey", "CD123");
    inboxDetailObj.put("action", "1");
    inboxDetailObj.put("idstatus", "");
    inboxDetailObj.put("noOfRows", "0");
    ...

    new PullInboxDetails(this, inboxDetailObj).execute();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Mysterious glad to know, if so please mark the question as answered.